# How to select all the tags under given node without getting the value of the tagged element in xml

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, soapui

I have below xml query:

```
     <return>
        <code>success</code>
        <message/>
        <deal>
           <checksum>203591</checksum>
           <documentID>21783</documentID>
           <dealStatus>P</dealStatus>
           <financing>
              <financeType>L</financeType>
              <term>32</term>
           </financing>
           <options>
              <disclosureType/>
              <frontBackFlag>P</frontBackFlag>
              <hardSoftFlag>M</hardSoftFlag>
              <optionCode>TO</optionCode>
              <optionDescription>QAfhggddate DOCID  219</optionDescription>
              <optionOrigin>xxx</optionOrigin>
              <optionPrice>
                 <optionPricingType>INVIICE</optionPricingType>
                 <price>111.99</price>
              </optionPrice>
              <optionPrice>
                 <optionPricingType>RETAIL</optionPricingType>
                 <price>2.99</price>
              </optionPrice>
              <optionResidualAmount>3.99</optionResidualAmount>
              <residualTableAmount>0.00</residualTableAmount>
              <residualTableFlag>N</residualTableFlag>
              <satisfiedDate>2012-05-08T00:00:00-06:00</satisfiedDate>
           </options>
        </deal>
     </return>
```

I need to put a checkpoint to verify that the above response have only fields that are mentioned in our specs. for eg. optionPrice should have only optionPricingType & price tags.So how to write xpath or xqery to get all the tags label under optionPrice without their values.

I am using SOAP UI to put assertions

Comment: <return>
            <code>success</code>
            <message/>
            <options>
                  <disclosureType/>
                  <optionOrigin>xxx</optionOrigin>
                  <optionPrice>
                     <optionPricingType>INVOICE</optionPricingType>
                     <price>111.99</price>
                  </optionPrice>
                  <optionPrice>
                     <optionPricingType>RETAIL</optionPricingType>
                     <price>222.99</price>
                  </optionPrice>
                 </options>
            </deal>
         </return>

Answer (score 2):

1. According to SoapUI's "[Functional Testing](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/functional-testing.html)" documentation, you can make assertions about **schema compliance**.  I recommend using this facility to verify that the response complies with your specification.
2. If you want/have to use XPaths, here are some ideas.  Assuming XPath 2.0 is available since in SoapUI "both the XPath and XQuery Match assertions make use of the Saxon XPath / XQuery processor which supports most of the latest standards in this area." Reference: [Validating XML Messages](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/xpath-and-xquery-assertions.html)

(#2 continued...) You can **test for the presence of known elements** (all expected results would be true):

```
boolean(/return)
boolean(/return/code)
boolean(/return/deal)
boolean(/return/deal/checksum)
```

Etc.  Note that this does not test for element ordering, which may or may not be significant to you.

You can **test for the absence of unknown elements** (expected result would be true):

```
min(for $elName in //*/local-name() return $elName = ('return','code','message','deal','checksum','documentID','dealStatus','financing','financeType','term','options','disclosureType','frontBackFlag','hardSoftFlag','optionCode','optionDescription','optionOrigin','optionPrice','optionPricingType','price','optionPrice','optionPricingType','price','optionResidualAmount','residualTableAmount','residualTableFlag','satisfiedDate'))
```

*Note the hack of using `min` over a list of booleans to effectively implement logical AND over the passing of each individual tag name test result.*

You can make various other spot checks via XPath assertions, but do try to use the schema conformance facilities mentioned in #1 if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The next XPath will extract the node names from `optionPrice`:

```
/return/deal/options/optionPrice/*/local-name()
```